# definition of "closed monoidal functor"

Tags: category-theory, functors, monoidal-categories

> A **(strong) monoidal functor** $F:C\to C'$ between monoidal categories
> is a functor equipped with natural isomorphisms $$ F_0:I'\cong F(I) $$
> $$ (F_2)_{A,B}:F(A)\otimes'F(B)\cong F(A\otimes B) $$ such that some
> certain diagrams commute (see
> https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+functor).
>
> A **(right-)closed monoidal category** is a monoidal category where
> for every object $B$, the functor $-\otimes B$ has a right adjoint
> $[B,-]$. (Note we can assemble the $[B,-]$ functors into a single
> bifunctor $[-,-]:C^{op}\times C\to C$ in a canonical way).

I was wondering if someone could provide a precise definition of what it means to be a "closed monoidal functor", if such a definition exists?

The best I could find was a discussion on how lax monoidal functors give rise to lax closed functors on https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+functor.

Comment: Note that every closed monoidal category is both a monoidal category and a closed category. We can then define a closed monoidal functor to be a functor that is [(lax) monoidal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+functor) and [(lax) closed](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+functor).

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the notion of closed category by itself (i.e. the definition that does not use the monoidal structure). I guess what I'm looking for here is a more streamlined definition of "closed monoidal functor", that is given directly in terms of the closed monoidal structure, rather than referring to the closed structure + the monoidal structure separately.

Comment: But isn’t it precisely what you want? A monoidal closed functor ought to be a functor preserving the monoidal product and the internal homs. So I would guess it is a strong monoidal strong closed functor. If you prefer lax notions everything will be even easier: a functor is lax monoidal iff it is lax closed (if I am not mistaken), so the term monoidal closed functor is redundant in this case…

Comment: Do you mean that you're hoping for a condition under which a monoidal functor is automatically also closed?

Comment: @KevinArlin I think this is closer to what I am after, yes

Comment: @PrudiiArca I don't think saying a monoidal closed functor is one that "preserves monoidal product and internal homs" is sufficient. 

If you look at the definition of closed functor (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+functor), there are a number of extra commuting diagrams that we need, which involve the $i$ natural transformation and $j$ extranatural transformation that are used to define a closed category (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+category). Ideally I am looking for a definition that does not involve the $i$, $j$, or $L$ transformations, etc.

Comment: To put my question another way, there is a definition of "closed functor" between "closed categories", which makes no reference to monoidal structure. 

A "monoidal closed category" is a particular instance of a closed category, and can be defined without any reference to the $i$, $j$, $L$, etc that appear in the definition of closed category. 

So it feels to me like the general definition of "closed functor" should reduce to a specific definition for monoidal closed categories which also does not need to reference $i$, $j$, $L$ etc.